# In Python, how can I count the number of files a sender has attached to an email?

Tags: python, email

This is a self-answered question, I would value any input / comments / code review. I *think* it works but not sure. My tests appears to yield valid results but email is a subtle and complex beast. I'm not sure that my logic is sound. If you would like to test it, save a raw email file and put the filename in the code, should be obvious where.  Is there a better way to do this?  If yes I'd love to hear it.

Python 2.7 code.

```
import email

filename = 'xxx.eml'

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    msg = email.message_from_file(f)

    # count number of attachments in an email
    # this determines the 'real' attachments, ie those that a user might have attached to the email
    # it does not include the attachments that make up the message content
    totalattachments = 0
    firsttextattachmentseen = False
    lastseenboundary = ''
    # .walk steps through all the parts of an email including boundaries and attachments
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.is_multipart():
            # this is a boundary, not an attachment, so we record it as the last seen boundary and continue to next part
            lastseenboundary = part.get_content_type()
            continue
        if lastseenboundary == 'multipart/alternative':
            #for HTML emails, the multipart/alternative part contains the HTML and its alternative 
            #text representation, so we skip anything within the multipart/alternative boundary
            continue
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            #if this is a plain text email, then the first txt attachment is the message body so we do not 
            #count it as an attachment
            if firsttextattachmentseen == False:
                firsttextattachmentseen = True
                continue
            else:
                totalattachments += 1
                continue
        # any other part we encounter we shall assume is a user added attachment
        totalattachments += 1

    print(totalattachments, ': ', filename)
```

Comment: Since you have a working solution you should have asked on codereview.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that many (all?) emails that have a multipart/alternative boundary contain text/plain then text/html and then go straight on to include file attachments.  Are emails meant to be structured that way?  I didn't think so, but there you have it.

So here is an updated version that treats all parts within the multpart/alternative boundary that come after the text and html, as attachments.

Email.... ugh.

```
import email

filename = 'xxx.eml'

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    msg = email.message_from_file(f)

    # count number of attachments in an email
    #
    totalattachments = 0
    firsttextattachmentseen = False
    lastseenboundary = ''
    # .walk steps through all the parts of an email including boundaries and attachments
    alternativetextplainfound = False
    alternativetexthtmlfound = False
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.is_multipart():
            # this is a boundary, so we record what the last seen boundary was and continue to next part
            lastseenboundary = part.get_content_type()
            continue
        if lastseenboundary == 'multipart/alternative':
            #for HTML emails, the multipart/alternative part contains the HTML and its alternative text representation
            #BUT it seems that plenty of messages add file attachments after the txt and html, so we'll have to account for that
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain' and alternativetextplainfound == False:
                alternativetextplainfound = True
                continue
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html' and alternativetexthtmlfound == False:
                alternativetexthtmlfound = True
                continue
        if (part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain') and (lastseenboundary != 'multipart/alternative'):
            #if this is a plain text email, then the first txt attachment is the message body so we do not 
            #count it as an attachment
            if firsttextattachmentseen == False:
                firsttextattachmentseen = True
                continue
            else:
                totalattachments += 1
                continue
        # any other part we encounter we shall assume is a user added attachment
        totalattachments += 1

    print(totalattachments, ': ', filename)
```

Comment: You don't need to include `==False` when testing a boolean condition.  It's really unnecessary and borderline smelly.  Also, `and (lastseenboundary != 'multipart/alternative'):` is unnecessary because you checked the condition above.